# does super(A,cls).__new__(cls) create an instance of base class?

Tags: python

```
class A:  
    def __new__(cls):  
        return super(A,cls).__new__(cls)
```

Comment: no it only run the same code as in parent class

Comment: I think you asked the wrong question. If you want to know whether it returns an instance of the base class, all you need to do is *try it*. So what's your *real* question? Do you want to know *why* it does what it does?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Looks like a homework question, or at the least, a very general question about programming and not a specific problem.

Comment: what is the difference between the parameters that super method accepts? Are they same class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it doesn't. It creates an instance of what you want.

Let's split down all your statements.

First, we declare a new class `A`:

```
class A:
```

By default, all classes inherit from `object`, so your declaration is the same as:

```
class A(object):
```

Next, you overwrite the definition for `__new__`:

```
def __new__(cls):
```

This is a function that takes the `class` object you want to instantiate.

Next, we call our base's class `__new__` method:

```
super(A, cls) # This refers to the base class of A, which is object
.__new__(cls) # Calls object.__new__(cls), with cls being the class you want to instantiate
```

`object.__new__` does the right job, in fact you can pass in any class you want and it will correctly instantiate it.

So, your `A.__new__` is just a delegate to `object.__new__`, so really, your `A.__new__` is completely useless, you can remove it and everything will work the same.

Having said that, when you do `A()`, this will trigger `A.__new__(A)`, which will trigger `object.__new__(A)`, so you'll end up with an instance of `A`.

If you were to have the following class:

```
class B(A):
    def __new__(cls):
        super(B, cls).__new__(cls)
```

The flow would be the same.

`B()` would trigger `B.__new__(B)` which would trigger `A.__new__(B)`, which would trigger `object.__new__(B)`, so you'd end up with an instance of `B`

Comment: what is the difference between the parameters that super method accepts? Are they same class? –